# How to transfer dictionary to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

There is dictionary `dic_1`  , i want transfer it to `dataframe` (the result just like the result of `val_1.append(val_2)`), but code `pd.DataFrame(dic_1)` failed .How to fixed it ?

```
import pandas as pd
val_1 = pd.DataFrame({'category':['a','b'],'amount':[1,3]})
val_2 = pd.DataFrame({'category':['d','e'],'amount':[4,7]})
dic_1 ={'v01':val_1,'v02':val_2}
```

below code failed

```
 pd.DataFrame(dic_1)
```

Comment: Do you need keys `'v01','v02'` in the final dataframe?

Comment: as row or column indices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

val_1 = pd.DataFrame({'category':['a','b'],'amount':[1,3]})
val_2 = pd.DataFrame({'category':['d','e'],'amount':[4,7]})
dic_1 ={'v01':val_1,'v02':val_2}    
df = pd.concat(dic_1.values(), ignore_index=True)    
print(df)
```

ignore_index=True makes sure that the index is reset in the resulting DataFrame.

The output

```
  category  amount
0        a       1
1        b       3
2        d       4
3        e       7
```

If you want to keep track of the original DataFrames, you can remove ignore_index=True and instead add keys=dic_1.keys().

```
df = pd.concat(dic_1.values(), keys=dic_1.keys())
```

output:

```
      category  amount
v01 0        a       1
    1        b       3
v02 0        d       4
    1        e       7
```

Answer (score 0):

pd.DataFrame expects input to be of following type
{columname: values as list}
But you are passing dataframe as value

Comment: Thanks. Right, so I met question about row bind it .